# Rmarkdown position of a logo in html document

Tags: yaml, r-markdown

I start with Rmarkdown and I want personalize my html document. I want to put a logo in the upper right corner of my document.

thanks!

I used includes option with before_body, but it puts the logo at the left corner. How could I put this logo at right corner?

output:

```
html_document:    

   includes:    

       before_body: Logo.html
```

Comment: You could include it in your title field like `title: "Test <img src=\"unnamed.png\" style=\"float: right;\"/> "`

Comment: @Martin Schmelzer thanks! that works! I also try the same thing with a logo at the end of my html document, I tried after body but it put the logo at the left. Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way for a topside log is to use corresponding HTML code in the title field. For a logo at the bottom of the page you can simply add the HTML code at the bottom of your document.

```
---
title: "Test <img src=\"unnamed.png\" style=\"float: right;\"/> "
author: "me"
date: "1/27/2019"
output: html_document

---

## Table

<img src="unnamed.png" style="float: right;" />
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your response, but i can't install jQuery package, wheni tried install.packages("jQuery "), it gives me : package ‘jQuery ’ is not available (for R version 3.5.2).

Comment: You dont have to install anything. It is not a R package anyhow.

Comment: I tried yr script code with my document's paths , that doesn't work for me, it's weird, it didn'te ven give me any error or warnings when kniting Rmarkdown

Comment: that works for me , i suppress the paths and keep only the name of my image. thank you!